# Laravel 5.2 mail-tracker

Tags: php, laravel-5

I build new project using laravel  5.2 and I want track emails opens,clicks and bounced emails .  But I didn't found the best. If you know please point me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This two package will be use full for you :

1. https://github.com/jdavidbakr/mail-tracker
2. https://github.com/ipunkt/laravel-analytics

Comment: thank you for your interest  . I need link to mail-tracker documentation  I already try to do it with mail-tracker but their is not documentation to mail tracker